# Empty Iterator : Asynchronous cassandra write

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

I am trying to implement asynchronous cassandra writes on objects (not RDD) using TableWriter. Code snippet below:

```
class CassandraOperations[T] extends Serializable with Logging {

  /**
    * Saves the data from object or Iterator of object to a Cassandra table asynchronously. Uses the specified column names.
    * You can check whether this action is completed or not by callback on Future.
    */
  def saveToCassandraAsync(
      cc: CassandraConnector,
      keyspaceName: String,
      tableName: String,
      columns: ColumnSelector = AllColumns,
      data: Iterator[T],
      writeConf: WriteConf = WriteConf(ttl = TTLOption.constant(80000)))(implicit rwf: RowWriterFactory[T]):
      Future[Unit] = {

    implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.global
    val writer = TableWriter(cc, keyspaceName, tableName, columns, writeConf)
    val futureAction =  Future(writer.write(TaskContext.get(), data: Iterator[T]))

    futureAction
  }
}
```

And then wait using:

```
Await.result(resultFuture, TIMEOUT seconds)
```

the data is available when the execution reaches the write method on line :

```
val futureAction =  Future(writer.write(TaskContext.get(), data: Iterator[T]))
```

But data is empty when the execution reaches the definition `def write(taskContext: TaskContext, **data**: Iterator[T])` of function :

```
def write(taskContext: TaskContext, data: Iterator[T]) {
    val updater = OutputMetricsUpdater(taskContext, writeConf)
    connector.withSessionDo { session =>
      val protocolVersion = session.getCluster.getConfiguration.getProtocolOptions.getProtocolVersion
      val rowIterator = new CountingIterator(data)
      val stmt = prepareStatement(session).setConsistencyLevel(writeConf.consistencyLevel)
      val queryExecutor = new QueryExecutor(
          session,
          writeConf.parallelismLevel,
          Some(updater.batchFinished(success = true, _, _, _)),
          Some(updater.batchFinished(success = false, _, _, _)))

      val routingKeyGenerator = new RoutingKeyGenerator(tableDef, columnNames)
      val batchType = if (isCounterUpdate) Type.COUNTER else Type.UNLOGGED

      val boundStmtBuilder = new BoundStatementBuilder(
          rowWriter,
          stmt,
          protocolVersion = protocolVersion,
          ignoreNulls = writeConf.ignoreNulls)

      val batchStmtBuilder = new BatchStatementBuilder(
          batchType,
          routingKeyGenerator,
          writeConf.consistencyLevel)

      val batchKeyGenerator = batchRoutingKey(session, routingKeyGenerator) _
      val batchBuilder = new GroupingBatchBuilder(
          boundStmtBuilder,
          batchStmtBuilder,
          batchKeyGenerator,
          writeConf.batchSize,
          writeConf.batchGroupingBufferSize,
          rowIterator)
      val rateLimiter = new RateLimiter((writeConf.throughputMiBPS * 1024 * 1024).toLong, 1024 * 1024)

      logDebug(s"Writing data partition to $keyspaceName.$tableName in batches of ${writeConf.batchSize}.")

      for (stmtToWrite <- batchBuilder) {
        queryExecutor.executeAsync(stmtToWrite)
        assert(stmtToWrite.bytesCount > 0)
        rateLimiter.maybeSleep(stmtToWrite.bytesCount)
      }

      queryExecutor.waitForCurrentlyExecutingTasks()

      if (!queryExecutor.successful)
        throw new IOException(s"Failed to write statements to $keyspaceName.$tableName.")

      val duration = updater.finish() / 1000000000d
      logInfo(f"Wrote ${rowIterator.count} rows to $keyspaceName.$tableName in $duration%.3f s.")
      if (boundStmtBuilder.logUnsetToNullWarning) {
        logWarning(boundStmtBuilder.UnsetToNullWarning)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

so I see empty iterator.

Please guide on what can be the issue.